# Creating new variables to R data.frame by summing based on factors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an R dataframe of following form:

```
FIRM   WORKER HOURS
FIRM1  A1     H1
FIRM1  A2     H2
FIRM1  A3     H3
FIRM1  B1     H4
FIRM1  B2     H5 
FIRM2  A1     H6
FIRM2  C1     H7
```

There are firms that have workers on different categories of education (A,B,C,...). I want to transform the dataframe so that education categories would sum up to an own column and all of the firms would have only one row for each. So I need to transform the initial dataframe into a following form:

```
FIRM   HOURS_A   HOURS_B HOURS_C
FIRM1  H1+H2+H3  H4+H5  
FIRM2  H6                H7
```

What would be the neatest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate and then reshape:

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
FIRM   WORKER HOURS
FIRM1  A1     1
FIRM1  A2     2
FIRM1  A3     3
FIRM1  B1     4
FIRM1  B2     5 
FIRM2  A1     6
FIRM2  C1     7
")
```

Code:

```
tmp <- aggregate(HOURS~FIRM+WORK, data=within(x, WORK <- substr(WORKER,1,1)), sum)

reshape(tmp, idvar="FIRM", timevar="WORK", direction="wide")
```

Result:

```
   FIRM HOURS.A HOURS.B HOURS.C
1 FIRM1       6       9      NA
2 FIRM2       6      NA       7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you actually want to sum certain values and that your data.frame looks something like this:

```
mydf <- structure(
  list(FIRM = c("FIRM1", "FIRM1", "FIRM1", "FIRM1", "FIRM1", "FIRM2", "FIRM2"), 
       WORKER = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C"), 
       HOURS = c(10L, 20L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 9L, 16L)), 
  .Names = c("FIRM", "WORKER", "HOURS"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
mydf
#    FIRM WORKER HOURS
# 1 FIRM1      A    10
# 2 FIRM1      A    20
# 3 FIRM1      A    15
# 4 FIRM1      B    13
# 5 FIRM1      B    12
# 6 FIRM2      A     9
# 7 FIRM2      C    16
```

Then, you can use `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(HOURS ~ FIRM + WORKER, mydf)
#        WORKER
# FIRM     A  B  C
#   FIRM1 45 25  0
#   FIRM2  9  0 16
```

Or, you can `melt` your dataset and reshape it with `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
dfL <- melt(mydf, id.vars=c("FIRM", "WORKER"))
dcast(dfL, FIRM ~ variable + WORKER, fun.aggregate=sum, value.var="value")
#    FIRM HOURS_A HOURS_B HOURS_C
# 1 FIRM1      45      25       0
# 2 FIRM2       9       0      16
```